# Google Sheet Query Delete Entire Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in google sheet, Let's say the named sheet is and **Logbook Form** and **Logbook Hold**. In sheet Logbook Hold has seven columns as below:

[image]

Before that, i have created formula query from sheet Logbook Form where Column L is hold. My goal is if column G (Final Status) in sheet Logbook Hold is not blank (has values "Close"), then the entire row is automatically delete. Here's an example:

[image]

Can somebody help me with this please? Please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean delete, or keep the value from being in the query? It looks like you're only pulling 3 columns of data (A, L, B), so how is column G pulling a value of close?

Comment: Value in column G (sheet Logbook Hold) i input manually sir. If I fill "Close" In column G, then the row automatically delete sir. Is it possible?

Comment: `then the row automatically delete` If you wish to physically delete a row, then you can't do that with a formula. So just to clarify: if you manually enter "Close" in any row of the sheet displaying the query, then you want the row relating to the relevant IDPrimary to be physically deleted from the sheet="Logbook Form". Is that correct?

Comment: FYI: `If you are replying to someone who has previously commented on the same post, mention their username, such as @pgSystemTester. While entering or editing a comment, typing "@" will provide a list of users you can notify. Clicking a username from the list will automatically fill out the @reply so you don't have to enter it manually. **This will create a notification in that user's global inbox so that they know that you have replied to them.**

Comment: `Can somebody help me with this please?` This is not a good description of a problem. Now that we have established that you need to use a script to delete the row (perhaps trigger the script with `onEdit`, and find the IDPrimary on `Logbook Form` using `indexOf`). You need to look at how you can resolve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Tedinoz good job. I agree!

Comment: @AkhmadFahrudhin if you can type in `close`, why not just delete it? Chances are you're going the wrong direction for a solution.

Comment: Further to the suggestion by @pgSystemTester for a manual delete.... But say the volume of transactions makes it too hard to find manually. An option would be an INDEX/MATCH formula adjacent to the “Close” column; the formula would show the row number in the "Logbook Form" sheet and it can be deleted manually.